# How to create ADFS session using ADFS APIs

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, adfs, openid-connect

I want to create an ADFS session in the browser using APIs only.

I don't want to redirect users to ADFS login page. I collect user's AD credentials and using those credentials I want to create ADFS as well as my site's session in the browser. Currently, I can create my site's session but not ADFS's session.

For this, I am using OIDC's Password Grant flow which works fine as I am getting access_token, id_token and refresh_token but it does not create ADFS's session in the browser.

I am using other federated applications with the same ADFS, so ADFS's session in the browser is critical for me.

Creating User session using APIs is supported in OneLogin (https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/login-user-via-api) and I want a similar approach for ADFS.

I am also open to any other approach which can help me achieve this goal.

If anybody can help me with it, it will be a BIG RELIEF.

ADFS Version: 4.0

OIDC Flow: Resource Owner Password Credentials

Answer (score 0):

ADFS (and Microsoft Identity products in general) do not have authentication API.

You can do this via WCF (WS-Fed active profile) but this by definition is not browser-based.

Comment: So is there any legitimate way of creating an ADFS session in the browser? I don't want to do it from backend. My apps are SPAs and they do not have any backend as such.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Yeah, I also think so. Thank you for your reply